# return a json error in middleware?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm building an app and I'm using laravel5 as webAPI.
When the webAPI is in Maintenance Mode, I want to return a json error to app and I will get the status code in app to show a suitable message.

I rewrite the laravel CheckForMaintenanceMode for somereason and registed it in Kernel.

I write

```
if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance()) {
    $ip = $request->getClientIp();
    $allowIp = "111.222.333.444";
    if ($allowIp != $ip) {
        return response()->json(['error' => "Maintenance!!"], 503);
    }
}
return $next($request);
```

But I can get NOTHING in app side.I cannot get the message, the satus....

I writh the same code like `return response()->json(['error' => "errormessage"], 422);` in controller and I can get the message.status.. in app but I cannot do the same thing in a middleware.

why? how to do it?

Comment: Does `return response(['Maintenance'], 503);` work? I have that in a middleware of my own on 5.4.

Comment: No it didn't work.cannot get the message and status code.

Comment: Thank you @Joe .I fount the answer!! I replaced the middleware not in Kernel global HTTP middleware but the route(api.php), it worked.

Answer (score 7):

This worked:

```
if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance()) {
    $ip = $request->getClientIp();
    $allowIp = "111.222.333.444";
    if ($allowIp != $ip) {
        return response(['Maintenance'], 503);
    }
}
return $next($request);
```

And not register the middleware in Kernel global HTTP middleware but put it in the route(api.php),like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'maintenance'], function(){******}
```

I really donot know why but this worked for me.

Comment: If you don't register middleware in Kernel it won't be able to load it, you'll get something like `ReflectionException Class maintenance does not exist`

Answer (score 5):

**Full example**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->token == "mytoken")
            return $next($request);
        else  return response(['Token mismatch'],403);
    }
```

**Explanation**

The **response** of a middleware
`must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`

so, for return a json, you have to do this

```
return response(['Token mismatch'],403);
```

The middleware must be registered in `Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way to do it is to extend the

`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode` class

and change it as per our needs and update the `App\Http\Kernel.php` like so..

> App\Http\CustomMaintanceMiddleware.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode;

class CustomMaintanceMiddleware extends CheckForMaintenanceMode
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance()) {
        return response(['Maintenance'], 503);
      }
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class
];
```

TO

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\CustomMaintanceMiddleware::class
];
```